# Where can i find ROW_NUMBER(), RANK(), DENSE_RANK() functions?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Where can i find ROW_NUMBER(), RANK(), DENSE_RANK() functions, like all other functions in sql server 2012 i can find in Programmability->Functions->System Functions

Comment: What do you mean with "find" the functions? They are all documented in the manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql Specifically under [Ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql)

Comment: These are functions defined by the T-SQL language. They are not listed in the places you refer to.

Comment: like we can see the list of function under Programmability->Functions->System Functions

Comment: I'm asking this in reference of sql server 2012. There you can find the list of all system function in your database under Programmability->Functions->System Functions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your statement that "you can find the list of all system function[s] in your database" is accurate - I looked through all the sections and I didn't see those three.

Why do you need to find them, though?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm a trainee, someone asked me to locate row_number() in those sections, i couldn't find it i searched google also but no luck that's why i asked here.

Comment: Well, if that's all there is to that task then it looks like your answer is "they aren't there".